IntelliJ Scala 2.13.0 no longer compiles - Error compiling the sbt component 'compiler-bridge-2.13.0-66.0'
I am working on a hobby project on my desktop using Scala 2.13.0 and JDK 22. The project compiles and runs perfectly fine there. This project is also on my personal GitHub. Because I went on holiday to Norway, I decided to clone it on my laptop. I updated my JDK to 22 there as well and have updated my system variables to properly refer to that Java version. I can select JDK 22 as well in IntelliJ and have also selected Scala JDK 2.13.0 as I have on my desktop at home. Yet, when I attempt to compile it (and any other Scala project on my laptop using any other JDK for that matter), it straight up fails with errors I have never seen before. I have spent hours and hours trying to find any solutions, but I am at a complete loss at this point. I have collected the following errors and stacktraces with the final error only taking place when rebuilding after already having had a failed build before:
scala: error:
  bad constant pool index: 0 at pos: 49176
     while compiling: <no file>
        during phase: globalPhase=<no phase>, enteringPhase=<some phase>
     library version: version 2.13.0
    compiler version: version 2.13.0
  reconstructed args: -nowarn -d C:\Users\Jelle\AppData\Local\Temp\sbt_642cc40 -classpath C:\Users\Jelle\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IdeaIC2024.1\plugins\Scala\lib\jps\sbt-interface.jar;C:\Users\Jelle\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IdeaIC2024.1\plugins\Scala\lib\jps\compiler-interface.jar;C:\Users\Jelle\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IdeaIC2024.1\plugins\Scala\lib\jps\compiler-bridge-sources_2.13.jar;C:\Users\Jelle\.m2\repository\org\scala-lang\scala-compiler\2.13.0\scala-compiler-2.13.0.jar;C:\Users\Jelle\.m2\repository\org\scala-lang\scala-reflect\2.13.0\scala-reflect-2.13.0.jar -bootclasspath C:\Users\Jelle\.m2\repository\org\scala-lang\scala-library\2.13.0\scala-library-2.13.0.jar

  last tree to typer: EmptyTree
       tree position: <unknown>
            tree tpe: <notype>
              symbol: null
           call site: <none> in <none>

== Source file context for tree position ==




scala: error: scala.reflect.internal.FatalError:
  bad constant pool index: 0 at pos: 49176
     while compiling: <no file>
        during phase: globalPhase=<no phase>, enteringPhase=<some phase>
     library version: version 2.13.0
    compiler version: version 2.13.0
  reconstructed args: -nowarn -d C:\Users\Jelle\AppData\Local\Temp\sbt_642cc40 -classpath C:\Users\Jelle\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IdeaIC2024.1\plugins\Scala\lib\jps\sbt-interface.jar;C:\Users\Jelle\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IdeaIC2024.1\plugins\Scala\lib\jps\compiler-interface.jar;C:\Users\Jelle\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IdeaIC2024.1\plugins\Scala\lib\jps\compiler-bridge-sources_2.13.jar;C:\Users\Jelle\.m2\repository\org\scala-lang\scala-compiler\2.13.0\scala-compiler-2.13.0.jar;C:\Users\Jelle\.m2\repository\org\scala-lang\scala-reflect\2.13.0\scala-reflect-2.13.0.jar -bootclasspath C:\Users\Jelle\.m2\repository\org\scala-lang\scala-library\2.13.0\scala-library-2.13.0.jar

  last tree to typer: EmptyTree
       tree position: <unknown>
            tree tpe: <notype>
              symbol: null
           call site: <none> in <none>

== Source file context for tree position ==


    at scala.reflect.internal.Reporting.abort(Reporting.scala:68)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Reporting.abort$(Reporting.scala:64)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.abort(SymbolTable.scala:28)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser$ConstantPool.errorBadIndex(ClassfileParser.scala:394)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser$ConstantPool.getExternalName(ClassfileParser.scala:249)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.readParamNames$1(ClassfileParser.scala:839)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.parseAttribute$1(ClassfileParser.scala:845)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.$anonfun$parseAttributes$6(ClassfileParser.scala:915)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.parseAttributes(ClassfileParser.scala:915)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.parseMethod(ClassfileParser.scala:621)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.parseClass(ClassfileParser.scala:534)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.$anonfun$parse$2(ClassfileParser.scala:161)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.$anonfun$parse$1(ClassfileParser.scala:147)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.parse(ClassfileParser.scala:130)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$ClassfileLoader.doComplete(SymbolLoaders.scala:323)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$SymbolLoader.$anonfun$complete$2(SymbolLoaders.scala:230)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$SymbolLoader.complete(SymbolLoaders.scala:228)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.completeInfo(Symbols.scala:1544)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.info(Symbols.scala:1517)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions.scala$reflect$internal$Definitions$$enterNewMethod(Definitions.scala:48)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.String_$plus$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:1221)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.String_$plus(Definitions.scala:1221)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.syntheticCoreMethods$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:1505)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.syntheticCoreMethods(Definitions.scala:1487)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.symbolsNotPresentInBytecode$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:1518)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.symbolsNotPresentInBytecode(Definitions.scala:1518)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.init(Definitions.scala:1574)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.<init>(Global.scala:1204)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Driver.doCompile(Driver.scala:47)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainClass.doCompile(Main.scala:30)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Driver.process(Driver.scala:68)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Main.process(Main.scala)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at sbt.internal.inc.RawCompiler.getReporter$1(RawCompiler.scala:56)
    at sbt.internal.inc.RawCompiler.apply(RawCompiler.scala:77)
    at sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler$.$anonfun$compileSources$7(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:457)
    at sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler$.handleCompilationError$1(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:432)
    at sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler$.$anonfun$compileSources$5(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:453)
    at sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler$.$anonfun$compileSources$5$adapted(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:448)
    at sbt.io.IO$.withTemporaryDirectory(IO.scala:488)
    at sbt.io.IO$.withTemporaryDirectory(IO.scala:498)
    at sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler$.$anonfun$compileSources$2(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:448)
    at sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler$.$anonfun$compileSources$2$adapted(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:440)
    at sbt.io.IO$.withTemporaryDirectory(IO.scala:488)
    at sbt.io.IO$.withTemporaryDirectory(IO.scala:498)
    at sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler$.compileSources(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:440)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CompilerFactoryImpl$.org$jetbrains$jps$incremental$scala$local$CompilerFactoryImpl$$getOrCompileInterfaceJar(CompilerFactoryImpl.scala:194)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CompilerFactoryImpl.$anonfun$getScalac$2(CompilerFactoryImpl.scala:88)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:201)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CompilerFactoryImpl.$anonfun$getScalac$1(CompilerFactoryImpl.scala:82)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:242)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CompilerFactoryImpl.getScalac(CompilerFactoryImpl.scala:73)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CompilerFactoryImpl.createCompiler(CompilerFactoryImpl.scala:22)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CachingFactory.$anonfun$createCompiler$1(CachingFactory.scala:17)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.Cache.compute(Cache.scala:74)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.Cache.getOrUpdate(Cache.scala:63)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CachingFactory.createCompiler(CachingFactory.scala:16)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.LocalServer.doCompile(LocalServer.scala:41)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.LocalServer.compile(LocalServer.scala:28)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.compileLogic(Main.scala:210)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.$anonfun$handleCommand$1(Main.scala:193)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.decorated$1(Main.scala:180)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.handleCommand(Main.scala:190)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.serverLogic(Main.scala:163)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.nailMain(Main.scala:103)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main.nailMain(Main.scala)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at com.facebook.nailgun.NGSession.runImpl(NGSession.java:312)
    at com.facebook.nailgun.NGSession.run(NGSession.java:198)



scala: Error: Error compiling the sbt component 'compiler-bridge-2.13.0-66.0'
sbt.internal.inc.CompileFailed: Error compiling the sbt component 'compiler-bridge-2.13.0-66.0'
    at sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler$.handleCompilationError$1(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:436)
    at sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler$.$anonfun$compileSources$5(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:453)
    at sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler$.$anonfun$compileSources$5$adapted(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:448)
    at sbt.io.IO$.withTemporaryDirectory(IO.scala:488)
    at sbt.io.IO$.withTemporaryDirectory(IO.scala:498)
    at sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler$.$anonfun$compileSources$2(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:448)
    at sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler$.$anonfun$compileSources$2$adapted(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:440)
    at sbt.io.IO$.withTemporaryDirectory(IO.scala:488)
    at sbt.io.IO$.withTemporaryDirectory(IO.scala:498)
    at sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler$.compileSources(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:440)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CompilerFactoryImpl$.org$jetbrains$jps$incremental$scala$local$CompilerFactoryImpl$$getOrCompileInterfaceJar(CompilerFactoryImpl.scala:194)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CompilerFactoryImpl.$anonfun$getScalac$2(CompilerFactoryImpl.scala:88)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:201)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CompilerFactoryImpl.$anonfun$getScalac$1(CompilerFactoryImpl.scala:82)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:242)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CompilerFactoryImpl.getScalac(CompilerFactoryImpl.scala:73)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CompilerFactoryImpl.createCompiler(CompilerFactoryImpl.scala:22)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CachingFactory.$anonfun$createCompiler$1(CachingFactory.scala:17)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.Cache.compute(Cache.scala:74)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.Cache.getOrUpdate(Cache.scala:63)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CachingFactory.createCompiler(CachingFactory.scala:16)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.LocalServer.doCompile(LocalServer.scala:41)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.LocalServer.compile(LocalServer.scala:28)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.compileLogic(Main.scala:210)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.$anonfun$handleCommand$1(Main.scala:193)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.decorated$1(Main.scala:180)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.handleCommand(Main.scala:190)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.serverLogic(Main.scala:163)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.nailMain(Main.scala:103)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main.nailMain(Main.scala)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at com.facebook.nailgun.NGSession.runImpl(NGSession.java:312)
    at com.facebook.nailgun.NGSession.run(NGSession.java:198)



scala: Error: org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.ServerException
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at scala.util.hashing.MurmurHash3$.seqHash(MurmurHash3.scala:355)
    at scala.collection.Seq.hashCode(Seq.scala:41)
    at scala.collection.Seq.hashCode$(Seq.scala:41)
    at scala.collection.AbstractSeq.hashCode(Seq.scala:1190)
    at scala.runtime.Statics.anyHash(Statics.java:127)
    at scala.util.hashing.MurmurHash3.productHash(MurmurHash3.scala:76)
    at scala.util.hashing.MurmurHash3$.productHash(MurmurHash3.scala:343)
    at scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime$._hashCode(ScalaRunTime.scala:158)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.compiler.data.CompilerJars.hashCode(CompilerJars.scala:16)
    at scala.runtime.Statics.anyHash(Statics.java:127)
    at scala.util.hashing.MurmurHash3.productHash(MurmurHash3.scala:76)
    at scala.util.hashing.MurmurHash3$.productHash(MurmurHash3.scala:343)
    at scala.Some.hashCode(Option.scala:618)
    at scala.runtime.Statics.anyHash(Statics.java:127)
    at scala.util.hashing.MurmurHash3.productHash(MurmurHash3.scala:76)
    at scala.util.hashing.MurmurHash3$.productHash(MurmurHash3.scala:343)
    at scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime$._hashCode(ScalaRunTime.scala:158)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.compiler.data.CompilerData.hashCode(CompilerData.scala:5)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:338)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.getNode(HashMap.java:576)
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.get(LinkedHashMap.java:536)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.Cache.$anonfun$createPromise$1(Cache.scala:112)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.Cache.withLock(Cache.scala:144)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.Cache.createPromise(Cache.scala:106)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.Cache.compute(Cache.scala:69)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.Cache.compute(Cache.scala:97)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.Cache.compute(Cache.scala:97)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.Cache.compute(Cache.scala:97)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.Cache.compute(Cache.scala:97)



Does anyone have any idea what is happening here because I have no idea at this point what this is about. I wouldn't even expect to see anything about sbt because the project was selected with the idea option in IntelliJ. The latter may absolutely be relevant, it might be my ignorance writing that statement.
Thank you in advance.
EDIT:
Mateusz Kubuszok suggested in the comments Scala 2.13.0 does not support JDK 22.
I have updated my Scala to 2.13.14 and downgraded my JDK to 21. This has resolved the problem. Thank you very much for bringing this to my attention.

Update Scala, or downgrade JDK, JDK 22 is not supported on 2.13.0 - https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/jdk-compatibility/overview.html

I have updated my Scala to 2.13.14 and downgraded my JDK to 21. This has resolved the problem. Thank you very much for bringing this to my attention.
